# SQL - update column' null value with previous non-null value using select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql like below. I need to create a new table with the NULL values for `name` to be value for the previous non-null row.

#### table1

```
name    time    value
---------------------
john    11:00   324
NULL    12:00   645
NULL    13:00   324
jane    11:00   132
NULL    12:00   30
NULL    13:00   NULL
NULL    14:00   -1
```

#### output table

```
name    time    value
---------------------
john    11:00   324
john    12:00   645
john    13:00   324
jane    11:00   132
jane    12:00   30
jane    13:00   NULL
jane    14:00   -1
```

notes:

1. I cannot alter table1 due to permission restrictions, so probably
   need to create a new table.
2. The table `table1` doesn't have an `id` field

Comment: How do we know which row is previous? According to what?

Comment: @jarlh - from the way the data is ordered in table1

Comment: But that data isn't ordered.

Comment: Your problem may not be answerable because you need a column which can order your table in order to fill in the missing names.  Internally, your actual table contains the above records in no order whatsoever.

Comment: you can use the ctid. but you need to verify that a vacuum has not trashed it. and, the update sql is going to sorta hell of complicated.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - i've posted a new question for the case with `id` field that can be sorted here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40816356/3206440

Answer (score 0):

If you have consecutive records with null values, the following should work. I'm assuming you have an id column as before

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id) a.id,b.name FROM table1 a INNER JOIN

   (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name IS NOT NULL) b 

ON a.id > b.id 
   WHERE a.name IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id,b.id DESC
```