# SQL fill null values for a field in multiple rows as previous non null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access, netezza

I have a table in netezza (based on postgresql) like below. I need to create a new table with the NULL values for `name` to be replaced with value of `name` for the previous non-null row.

#### table1

```
id name time    value
---------------------
1 john  11:00   324
2 NULL  12:00   645
3 NULL  13:00   324
4 bane  11:00   132
5 NULL  12:00   30
6 NULL  13:00   NULL
7 NULL  14:00   -1
8 zane  11:00   152
9 NULL  12:00   60
10 NULL 13:00   NULL
```

#### output table

```
name    time    value
---------------------
john    11:00   324
john    12:00   645
john    13:00   324
bane    11:00   132
bane    12:00   30
bane    13:00   NULL
bane    14:00   -1
zane    11:00   152
zane    12:00   60
zane    13:00   NULL
```

notes:

1. Cannot alter table1 due to permission restrictions, so a new table
   is the way.
2. Need to run this in `Netezza` (preferably) or `MS Access`.

Code used to create the test data in Netezza is as below.

```
create temp table test (
    id int
    ,name varchar(10)
    ,time time
    ,value int
)distribute on random;

insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(1, 'joe', '10:00', 324);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(2, null, '11:00', 645);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(3, null, '12:00', 324);

insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(4, 'bane', '10:00', 132);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(5, null, '11:00', 30);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(6, null, '12:00', null);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(7, null, '13:00', -1);

insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(8, 'zane', '10:00', 152);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(9, null, '11:00', 60);
insert into test (id, name, time, value) values(10, null, '12:00', null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this recursive PostgreSQL query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id, name, time, value) AS (
  SELECT id, name, time, value FROM test WHERE id = (
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM test
  )
  UNION
  SELECT test.id, COALESCE(test.name, t.name), test.time, test.value
  FROM test, t WHERE test.id = (
    SELECT id FROM test WHERE id > t.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
  )
) SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id;
```

Notice though that this will probably issue a `SELECT` on each row. If you don't want that, you can use a view solution:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS
SELECT id, LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) lag_id, name, time, value FROM test;

WITH RECURSIVE t(id, name, time, value) AS (
  SELECT id, name, time, value FROM test_view WHERE lag_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test_view.id, COALESCE(test_view.name, t.name),
    test_view.time, test_view.value
  FROM test_view, t WHERE test_view.lag_id = t.id
) SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id;
```

This should be much faster. The idea is from [this article](http://mwrynn.blogspot.ru/2011/08/postgres-query-using-window-functions.html). SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/63f7b/1/1.

Comment: this should would have worked in Postgresql. However I need to run this on Netezza (based on Postgresql) and gets the following error while running it - `ERROR:  Recursive queries are not supported`. So seems recursive cannot be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Access 2010:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 t2.name
        FROM test t2
        WHERE t2.id<=t1.id AND t2.name IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY t2.id DESC
    ) AS name,
    t1.time,
    t1.value
FROM test t1
```

It should work in other SQL dialects as well, although they may have a slightly different way of doing `TOP 1` (e.g., `LIMIT 1` is a common variant).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `COALESCE` function and subqueries:

```
SELECT t.id, 
    COALESCE(t.name, (SELECT s.name FROM table s WHERE s.name IS NOT NULL AND s.id < t.id ORDER BY s.id LIMIT 1)) AS name,
    t.time,
    COALESCE(t.value, (SELECT s.value FROM table s WHERE s.value IS NOT NULL AND s.id < t.id ORDER BY s.id LIMIT 1)) AS value
FROM table t ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: this doesn't work. error: `"SELECT" (at char 31) expecting an identifier found a keyword`

Comment: Oh, the query needs more parentheses. I'll fix it.

Comment: error: `ERROR: (2) This form of correlated query is not supported` - consider rewriting. Also note that I'm running this in `Netezza` which is based on PostgreSQL

Comment: This may come from multiple result lines in the subquery. I've added an ordering and a limit.

Comment: tried this (on netezza) - but gets same error - `ERROR:  (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting`

Answer (score 0):

#### MS Access based solution

```
SELECT (SELECT last(name)
          FROM test AS temp
          WHERE test.id >= temp.id AND temp.name IS NOT NULL) AS new_name, *
FROM test;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the lead function. Not sure if that works with postgre, for Oracle it does. I think that can help.

Comment: How do you calculate the offset which is necessary for `LEAD`?

Comment: Good question. Didn't think about that.